# Openoffice Reference in ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, openoffice.org

I have to access OpenOffice in my current ASP.NET project. I installed "OpenOffice.org 3.4.1 SDK (en-US) Installation Files" after installing Open office SDK and am unable to find DLL to include in my project as a Reference.

How do I add a reference to asp.net application and how can I access the Spreadsheet through ASP.NET?

Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Updated the tag and a bit of the grammar.. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You could use the open office nuget package `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`. This will create the reference to the namespace for you as well.